# Remap Keys in Catalina

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I asked for, and received, key remapping instructions (Technical Note TN2450 -- but they were for High Sierra.  Are those instructions also correct for Catalina?  I want to remap the "num/clear" and change it to "del."

Comment: They're still the same.  Are you having an issue remapping them with those instructions?

Comment: Yes…here’s what I found in the tech note:

$ hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000004,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000005},{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000005,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000004}]}'
)

Do I just replace the two hexadecimal values for the key I want changed and use the entire string in Terminal?